# Java Pagination Page is returning null when results found in db is under 10

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, pagination

I am using hibernate and postgres.

I have an api call with pagination.  The total elements are 108.  I am getting null when I try to get content from the last page and not sure why.

[image]

When I use pagination and set page to 10 and size to 10 it works.

[image]

But when I change page to 11 I get null for content.

[image]

Here is the call in the controller

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/requirements") public Page<Scope> getScope(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Scope> reqPage = this.scopeService.findByBusinessId(id, pageable);
    if (reqPage.getSize() == 0) {
        Optional<Business> searchItem = businessService.findById(id);
        if (searchItem.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }
    }
    return reqPage; }
```

Here is the code in the service

```
public Page<Scope> findByBusinessId(UUID bId, Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.findByBusinessId(bId, pageable);
}
```

This is the call in the repository

```
public interface ScopeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Scope, UUID> {
    @Query("SELECT sr FROM Scope sr WHERE sr.business.id = :businessId")
    Page<Scope> findByBusinessId(UUID businessId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: I am wondering how to cast from `Page<ScopeRequirement>` to `Page<Scope>` - I think the problem is in the code you have not posted, because everything else looks ok.

Comment: @Ralph Page<ScopeRequirement> was a typo.  It is Page<Scope> in the code

Comment: I've never used whatever this thing is (postman?), but it sure looks like pages are numbered from 0, so the 11th page is page numbered 10.  And page numbered 11 is off the end of the data.

Answer (score 2):

The page count should be starting from 0.
i.e.

page 0 [1-10]
page 1 [11-20]
.
.
.
page 11 [110-120]

As you requesting page 11, there will be no content for that.
You can check the page on 10, you will get item 101-108.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).